# Immutability is an implementation detail in React?

Tags: reactjs

I recently watched a talk by David Nolen where he says that 'immutability is an implementation detail in React'?

What does this mean and if this wasn't the case, how would React be different?

Comment: I think he meant "how you choose to implement immutability is left up to you". That things are immutable is pretty important to React (and not something you do not have to care about -- which is what "implementation detail" usually implies).

Answer (score 1):

**What does "implementation detail" mean:**
I would summarize as:

> Immutability is a detail of react that you have to implement yourself.

BTW: "Detail" is this case can still mean a lot of work.

React depends on props and state to be immutable.
React does not make props or state immutable for you. You have to ensure that in your code yourself.

So the following code is a recipe for disaster:

```
// DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME
var customerObject = { name: "Bill" };
this.setState( customer: customerObject }; // valid react code, triggering re-render
...
customerObject.name = "Karl";
// state still has the same customerObject, 
// but the contents of the object have changed. This is where things break down.
```

React has to ensure that its internal virtual DOM, and all props and states, are always in sync with the actual DOM.
So every time something changes anywhere in a prop or state, react needs to run its render cycle.

**How would react be different without immutability:**
Without immutability your react implementation may not work properly.
If react were not designed for immutability, then it would not be react (i.e. a state machine) but a different beast altogether.

Answer (score 0):

**Immutable Data Structure with ReactJS**

The first of all, react team strongly recommend applying immutable data structure like [Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) or [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). Why? Because we can use "shallow comparison" to increase component re-render performance. like

```
MyComponent extends React.Component {

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !shallowEqual(this.props, nextProps) ||     
           !shallowEqual(this.state, nextState);
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

According to immutability, the data alway return a new reference if it has been changed. We can easy use shallowEqual(only check reference whether is same or not) to determine component will re-render. If we dont use immutable data, we have to check props or state object deeply not reference to make sure re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

As for my understanding, each component in React has its own standalone scope and they don't share the variables.

That means when you pass an **mutable** variable(such as `Object` or `Array`) through props to a specific react component. It will clone each variable so that this component will have a totally new environment.

For example, assuming you have component A, and it works like this,

```
var ComponentA = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var user = { name: 'Tyler', role: 'Developer' };
        return (
            <SubComponent user={user} />
        );    
    } 
});
```

What ComponentA wants is simply render the user. So it require another module, let's say **SubComponent** to do that.

```
var SubComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
               <span>Name: {this.props.user.name}</span>
               <span>Role: {this.props.user.role}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

For now, we should notice the variable `user` in ComponentA is different with the variable `this.props.user` in SubComponent. The `this.props.user` is not a reference. It's cloned from the ComponentA.

So that means, when you try to change the value of `this.props.user` in SubComponent, it won't destroy the `user` in ComponentA. Which is what David Nolen said in his tech talk. ("Change something in data without destroy the old one.")

Of course this would sacrifice some extra spaces, but you can get lots of benefits. Such as each of your component would be totally separated. Then all the nightmares cause by **Shared Mutable Variables** are gone. Shared Mutable Data is the root of evil, it's unpredictable and unreliable.

Imagine the **SubComponent** and the **ComponentA** are share the same `user` and you want to render another module by passing props `user`. Then you will update your code into this way,

```
 var ComponentA = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var user = { name: 'Tyler', role: 'Developer' };
        return (
            <div>
                <AnotherComponent user={user} />
                <SubComponent user={user} />
            </div>
        );    
    } 
});
```

Once we change the name of user in SubComponent(maybe by accident), we will have a cascading effect, and we don't know which one change the variable. That's painful coz then **we have to check each line of the code** in **SubComponent** and **AnotherComponent**. You really don't want to do that, right?

So I think that's what he mean. Hope this can solve your problem. : )